# PHP file_get_contents and Asana API

Tags: php, file-get-contents

I’m trying to retrieve some value from our asana workspace.

I’ve been able to do it with javascript

```
var bearerToken = "bearer APIKEY";
    var requestUrl = "https://app.asana.com/api/1.0/projects/PROJECTID/tasks"
     var headers = {
      "Authorization" : bearerToken

    };

    var reqParams = {
        method : "GET",
        headers : headers,
        muteHttpExceptions: true
      };

    let res= await fetch(requestUrl,reqParams); // (2)
```

But for safety reason, i’m trying to convert this code to PHP so :

```
$url = 'http://app.asana.com/api/1.0/projects/PROJECTID/tasks';


$opts = [
    "http" => [
        "method" => "GET",
        "header" => "Content-Type: application/json\r\n" .
            "charset=utf-8\r\n" ,
            "Authorization : bearer APIKEY \r\n"
    ]
];

$context = stream_context_create($opts);


$file = file_get_contents('app.asana.com/api/1.0/projects/1158939083333529/tasks', false, $context);

$file = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
$json_echo = json_decode($file)
 echo $json_echo;
```

The echo will return empty value …

Best regards

Comment: have you tried `var_dump($file);` just to see what is really returned? Maybe the json_encode() operation is failing. That would be the first debugging step you should take, to start tracing back to where the problem occurs.

Comment: You are not trying to read from any HTTP URL in your PHP code, you specified a relative _file system_ path.

Comment: you can try using curl

         $ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, requestUrl );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,
            "postvar1=value1&postvar2=value2&postvar3=value3");

// In real life you should use something like:
// curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 
//          http_build_query(array('postvar1' => 'value1')));

// Receive server response ...
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$server_output = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close ($ch);

Comment: I've tried with curl, seem to work but now I'm getting : {"errors":[{"message":"Not Authorized","help" ... There is something wrong with my headers : 

$headers = array('Authorization: Bearer APIKEY',  "Content-type: application/json");

Comment: Finally got it to work with :
$result1 = exec ('curl -u' .$apikey. ' : https://app.asana.com/api/1.0/projects/1158939083333529/tasks');

I don't know why the header auth is not working ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here a full functional code for anyone that might requires it:

```
$WCURL = 'https://app.asana.com/api/1.0/projects/projetc_id/tasks';
$CURLHTTPHeader = array(
    'Content-Type: application/json',
    'Accept: application/json',
    'Authorization: Bearer your_api_key');

$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$WCURL);
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postFields);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,$CURLHTTPHeader);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$curlResponse = curl_exec ($ch);
curl_close ($ch);

echo $curlResponse;
```

Comment: Thanks for this, been working through their API documented way of using PHP for a list of projects for hours, this has done it in minutes with half the load